# How can I get the value of contenteditable from my div a

Tags: php, jquery

How can I get the value of the contenteditable after I type on it?

Is there a way of getting the value of it after I click on the div and edit the text and send it to php?..

BTW i am using jquery and php for this.
Here is my Code:

```
<div class="profilestatus"> <a contenteditable>type text here</a></div>
```

Comment: have you tried putting it in a form?

Comment: Nope but ill try right now

Comment: Inputs always have to be in a form. Even when you're using AJAX and ignore the form's action, it's still clearer to put your inputs inside a form.

Comment: If you bear with me I am working on something :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var phrase = '<div class="profilestatus"> <a contenteditable>type text here</a></div>'; 
var myRegexp = YOUR MATCH PATTERN;
var match = myRegexp.exec(phrase);
alert(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `<input>` instead. You can use CSS to style it to look like the `<a>` if needed. You can get the current value of the input with `$('input').val();`.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9R5VE/
HTML:

```
<input value="editable"></input>
```

jQuery:

```
$("input").focusout(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: I am typing in the input but the text always dispeared when there is no area How can I make the text visible all the time in the text field.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe :

```
$('#yourForm').submit(function() {
    $('#hiddenInput').attr(
        'value',
        $('.profilestatus').first().children(0).html()
    );
});
```

?

You can also style a `<textarea>` using CSS. This would avoid you to have an hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying for ages to get the content to highlight automatically, but could not do it with neither JS nor jQuery :(

Anyway, this is what I have:

Working example: [here](http://www.danielabbey.co.uk/so/15957038/)

```
    <script>
        function formSubmit(content)
        {
            document.eForm.link.value = content;
            document.eForm.submit();
        }
    </script>
    <?php
        $link = isset($_POST['link']) ? $_POST['link'] : NULL;
        ($link !== NULL) ?
        ((stripos($link, 'http://') === FALSE) ?
        header('Location: http://'.strip_tags($link)) :
        header('Location: '.strip_tags($link))) : true;
    ?>
    <form name="eForm" method="Post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
        <input id="try" type="hidden" name="link" />
        <div id="eDiv" class="profilestatus" contenteditable>
            <a id="eLink" onclick="formSubmit(document.getElementById('eLink').innerHTML)">highlight, type, click!</a>
        </div>
    </form>
```